# Enumerating Environment keys with VBScript?

Tags: api, vbscript, environment-variables

I need to enumerate the *keys* in the `WScript.Shell.Environment` object. It's clear that if you already know the name of the key, you're home free with:

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Debug.WriteLine "PATH=" & oShell.Environment("PATH")
```

...but if you want to list the keys, it looks like you're out of luck!   Is there a secret passageway somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`WshEnvironment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s7w15a0.aspx) object is a collection, so you can enumerate it using VBScript's`For Each ... Next` statement:

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oEnv = oShell.Environment

For Each strVar in oEnv
  WScript.Echo strVar
Next
```

The output contains both environment variable names and values, like this:

```
ComSpec=%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=2
TEMP=%SystemRoot%\TEMP
TMP=%SystemRoot%\TEMP
windir=%SystemRoot%
...
```